# Changing the image in an img tag in svelte upon error

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a question on how to handle an image error while inside an #each loop in Svelte?

I am building an interface where users can select and switch between modules by accessing a quick access menu made of cards.

My intention is to trigger an error on `Title 2` in the `quickAccessMenu` and through the function, `handleImgError` fallback on the use of a default image for the card. But I am having difficulties getting the error function to change the image being used.

index.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    type quickAccessMenu = {
        "title": string;
        "image": string;
    }

    export const quickAccessMenu : quickAccessMenu[] = [
        { "title": "Menu Item 1", "image": "default.jpg" },
        { "title": "Menu Item 2", "image": "error.png" },
        { "title": "Menu Item 3", "image": "" }
    ];

    function handleImgError(i: number) {
        quickAccessMenu[i].image = "default.jpg";
    }
</script>

<div class="container">
    {#each quickAccessMenu as menu, i }
        <div class="small-card">
            <div class="card-bg-image">
                <p>{menu.title}</p>
                <div class="black-filter"></div>
                {
                    #if menu.image === "" 
                    || menu.image === null
                    || menu.image === undefined
                }
                    <img
                        src="/image/quick-access-menu/default.jpg"
                        alt="{menu.title} menu"
                    />
                {:else}
                    <img
                        src="/image/quick-access-menu/{menu.image}"
                        alt="{menu.title} menu"
                        on:error = {() => handleImgError(i)}
                    />
                {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it doesn't work because of SSR. To fix it, you need to add a browser guard.

First, import the `browser variable`:

```html
import { browser } from "$app/env"
```

Then check if you're in a browser when initializing `quickAccessMenu`:

```html
export const quickAccessMenu : quickAccessMenu[] = browser && [
    ...
];
```

Full example of the `script` tag:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { browser } from "$app/env";

    type quickAccessMenu = {
        "title": string;
        "image": string;
    }

    export const quickAccessMenu : quickAccessMenu[] = browser && [
        { "title": "Menu Item 1", "image": "default.jpg"},
        { "title": "Menu Item 2", "image": "error.png"},
        { "title": "Menu Item 3", "image": ""},
        { "title": "This should be an error", "image": "doesnt exist"},
    ];

    function handleImgError(i: number) {
        quickAccessMenu[i].image = "default.jpg";
    }
</script>
```

If you don't add the browser guard, the `on:error` event never actually fires, surprisingly. I am not aware if this is intended behaviour or a bug...

---

---

Also, just as a recommendation, you can simplify a lot your HTML markup using [the new `{@const ...} tag`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) like so:

```html
<div class="container">
    {#each quickAccessMenu as menu, i }
        {@const fileName = ["", null, undefined].includes(menu.image) ? 'default.jpeg' : menu.image}
        <div class="small-card">
            <div class="card-bg-image">
                <p>{menu.title}</p>
                <div class="black-filter"></div>
                <img
                    src="/image/quick-access-menu/{fileName}"
                    alt="{menu.title} menu"
                    on:error={() => handleImgError(i)}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

You can even simplify further the const assignment to `{@const fileName = menu.image || 'default.jpg'}` if you don't mind that 0, empty arrays and empty object are interpreted as undefined (which I doubt you do).